# Issue Logitech ergo keyboard: Cannot write greater or less than symbols on Mac (< >)

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, logitech-keyboard

I'm using Logitech's K860 keyboard on a Macbook and haven't found any way to output the greater or less than symbols. This keyboard is set up to **ISO** (Latin America).

The shift key is working correctly and every other symbol is okay as well.

Also, the Ergo keyboard has a key that's supposed to output both symbols on shift-pressed (and not pressed). But all I'm getting is the following:

- < : |
- .> : °

I would appreciate a lot any help.

**Edit:** I just found that switching the layout to ISO (Spanish) allows me to use an entirely different key to produce the <> symbols. But it also messes up with the rest of shortcut combinations, so it doesn't feel like an actual solution.

Edit 2: Attaching a picture of my keyboard layout
[Logitech keyboard layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxRRV.jpg)

Comment: We probably need a photo of the keyboard itself. Logitech make several versions of the same keyboard & those keys may naturally move depending on 'nationality' as well as input language.

Comment: Got it @Tetsujin , just included a link to the photo.

Answer (score 4):

After figuring out how to solve this issue, I found this repo https://github.com/neosergio/Latam-Keyboard. It's custom layout for LatinAmerican Keyboards, if you take a look to the repository you'll have more information

I had run this command

```
git clone https://github.com/neosergio/Latam-Keyboard.git && cd Latam-Keyboard && cp -v Latam*.* ~/Library/Keyboard\ Layouts/
```

After you had run the script go to "Open Keyboard preferences" And add a new Input Source:

[image: reference]

(Add > Others > "Latin American B")

In my case "Latin American B" did the trick but you can play with A B or C.

I hope it can help.

Comment: Hey this is it! after getting a mbp with Ventura I had this issue with a Logitech K380 and a K400+ keyboards. Tried Karabiner but couldn't get the correct layout setup. Using this repo configs really fixed for me for the < and > keys.

Comment: Finally, so amazing answer, thanks! For me it was Latin America A

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your keyboard to use this ‹› characters using the Logi Options software, it is no the best solution but it works, using a combination of keys to use the ascii code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrF4a.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEUhY.png)